# Why is TPrinter (XE7) suddenly having problems today?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I am using C++ Builder XE7 VCL.

Around August 11 2016 2:00pm UTC, I started receiving multiple complaints from my user base about printing problems. Most of these printing modules have proven stable for many years, and there were no updates to my project within the past 24 hours. I was able to reproduce similar problems on my development/test environment.

Without going into many details of my project, let me present a very simple printing program that is failing:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::PrintButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Test Print:
    TPrinter *Prntr = Printer();
    Prntr->Title = "Test_";
    Prntr->BeginDoc();
    Prntr->Canvas->Font->Size = 10;
    Prntr->Canvas->TextOut(300,1050,"* * * Printing Test * * *");
    if (Prntr->Printing) {
        Prntr->EndDoc();
    }
}
```

On the first attempt to print, everything works perfectly as expected.  If I click the button a second time, `TPrinter` produces a small PDF, but the PDF file is actually corrupted and appears to have a file handle stuck to it.

If I click the button a third time, I get no printing and the following error message appears:

```
Printer is not currently printing.
```

My own test was done using a PDF printer driver, but the complaints I am receiving from users include a variety of local printers, network printers, PDF printers, etc.

In my actual project, I have `try/catch` exception handling, so the actual results are slightly different, but substantially similar to this result.  The results show the hallmarks of instability and/or memory leaks without much in terms of error messages.

I suspect there may have been some Microsoft Windows updates that are tangling with Embarcadero DLLs, but I have not been able to verify this so far.

Is anyone else having similar problems?

Comment: Looking at VCL code FPrinting is not set when StartDoc fails. I suggest testing 'Printing' immediately after 'BeginDoc' and calling GetLastError if not printing.

Comment: We are getting reports of the same error today. Our tech support people had one of the customers roll back the updates from last night, and the printing started working. Just starting to look into it myself.

Comment: I've got this week's updates installed on Windows 7 64. A quick test using your code (adding a  single line to select the Snagit 11 printer at the top) works fine on Delphi 10.1 Berlin; I'm looking at the captured page as I type this.

Comment: Further testing indicates the problem shows up fairly consistently when the application is run in Windows 7 (Pro 64), but the problem does not seem to exist for a few tests where the application was run in Windows 10 Pro.  These tests are all based on C++ Builder XE7 (Update 1).

Comment: When the error happens, do other apps also fail to print using the same printer? I do not think this is a VCL issue, especially if the VCL app in question has not been changed before the error started occurring. This does seem like a Windows Update broke the print driver.

Comment: Other typical Windows apps such as MS Word, Adobe Reader, etc. seem to be able to print without problems along side the VCL based app that is not printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason using a `TPrintDialog` or `TPrinterSetupDialog` "works" to fix the error is because they force the singleton `TPrinter` object (returned by the `Vcl.Printers.Printer()` function) to release its current handle to a printer if it has one, thus causing `TPrinter.BeginDoc()` to create a new handle.  `TPrinter` releases its printer handle when:

- it is being destroyed.
- its `NumCopies`, `Orientation`, or `PrinterIndex` property is set.
- its `SetPrinter()` method is called (internally by the `PrinterIndex` property setter and `SetToDefaultPrinter()` method, and by `TPrintDialog` and `TPrinterSetupDialog`).

Without doing that, calling `TPrinter.BeginDoc()` multiple times will just keep re-using the same printer handle.  And apparently something about the recent Microsoft security update has now affected that handle reuse.

So, in short, (without uninstalling the Microsoft update) in between calls to `BeginDoc()` you need to do *something* that causes `TPrinter` to release and recreate its printer handle, and then the problem should go away.  At least until Embarcadero can release a patch to `TPrinter` to address this issue.  Maybe they could update `TPrinter.EndDoc()` or `TPrinter.Refresh()` to release the current printer handle (they currently do not).

Therefore, the following workaround resolves the printing issue without requiring any changes to the user interface:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::PrintButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Test Print:
    TPrinter *Prntr = Printer();
    Prntr->Title = "Test_";
    Prntr->Copies = 1;  // Here is the workaround
    Prntr->BeginDoc();
    if (Prntr->Printing) {
        Prntr->Canvas->Font->Size = 10;
        Prntr->Canvas->TextOut(300,1050,"* * * Printing Test * * *");
        Prntr->EndDoc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no Embarcadero DLLs involved in printing.  `TPrinter` simply calls Win32 API GDI-based print functions directly.

The "Printer is not currently printing" error occurs when one of the following operations is performed on a `TPrinter` when its `Printing` property is false:

- `TPrinter::NewPage()`
- `TPrinter::EndDoc()`
- `TPrinter::Abort()`
- a `TPrinter::Canvas` subproperty is being changed.
- the `TPrinter::Canvas` is being drawn on.

You are performing half of these operations in the test code you have shown, but you did not specify which line of code is actually throwing the error.

The `Printing` property simply returns the current value of the `TPrinter::FPrinting` data member, which is set to false only when:

- the `TPrinter` object is initially created (the `Printer()` function returns a singleton object that is reused for the lifetime of the executable).
- the Win32 API [`StartDoc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145114.aspx) function fails inside of `TPrinter::BeginDoc()` (`FPrinting` is set to true before `StartDoc()` is called).
- `TPrinter::EndDoc()` is called when `Printing` is true.

So, given the test code you have shown, there are two possibilities:

- `StartDoc()` fails and you are not checking for that condition.  `BeginDoc()` will not throw an error (VCL bug?!?), it will simply exit normally but `Printing` will be false.  Add a check for that:

  ```cpp
  Prntr->BeginDoc();
  if (Prntr->Printing) { // <-- here
      Prntr->Canvas->Font->Size = 10;
      Prntr->Canvas->TextOut(300,1050,"* * * Printing Test * * *");
      Prntr->EndDoc();
  }
  ```
- the `Printing` property is getting set to false prematurely while you are in the process of printing something.  The *only* ways that could happen in the code shown are if:

  - random memory is being corrupted, and `TPrinter` happens to be the victim.
  - multiple threads are manipulating the same `TPrinter` object at the same time.  `TPrinter` is not thread-safe.

Since you can reproduce the problem in your development system, I suggest you enable Debug DCUs in the project options, then run your app in the debugger, and put a data breakpoint on the `TPrinter::FPrinting` data member.  The breakpoint will be hit when `FPrinting` changes value, and you will be able to look at the call stack to see exactly which code is making that change.

Based on this information, I am going to go out on a limb and guess that the cause of your error is `StartDoc()` failing.  Unfortunately, `StartDoc()` is not documented as returning *why* it fails.  You certainly cannot use `GetLastError()` for that (most GDI errors are not reported by `GetLastError()`).  You *might* be able to use the Win32 API [`Escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162701.aspx) or [`ExtEscape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162708.aspx) function to retrieve an error code from the print driver itself (use `TPrinter::Canvas::Handle` as the `HDC` to query).  But if that does not work, you won't be able to determine the reason of the failure, unless Windows is reporting an error message in its Event Log.

If `StartDoc()` really is failing, it is because of an Win32 API failure, not a VCL failure.  Most likely the printer driver itself is failing internally (especially if a PDF print driver is leaving an open file handle to its PDF file), or Windows is failing to communicate with the driver correctly.  Either way, it is outside of the VCL.  This is consistent with the fact that the error started happening without you making any changes to your app.  A Windows Update likely caused a breaking change in the print driver.

Comment: StartDoc was previously documented to use GetLastError when the function fails. You can see it in XE2 api docs. Discussion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07323a9e-355b-463f-a167-1acaa70eb7e6/the-return-value-startdoc-function-is-not-compatible-with-last-error-code-by-getlasterror-function?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) hints that previous documentation might be wrong...

Comment: Interesting, MS support article [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983224) suggests that the current documentation might be wrong.

Comment: In that discussion thread, Rob Caplan at MS said: "*I confirmed that in current OSes StartDoc does not set last error on its error paths.*"  So yes, the documentation was wrong and was corrected. That is why the current MSDN documentation no longer says a `StartDoc()` error code can be retrieved from `GetLastError()`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I have tried the easier steps so far: the suggested code change and review Window Event Log.  All is quiet; no errors/messages.  So yes, most likely StartDoc() is failing.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the following Windows update:

Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3177725)

[MS16-098: Description of the security update for Windows kernel-mode drivers: August 9, 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177725)

This appears to resolve the issue for several test cases so far.

Answer (score 1):

It started happening here today too. On my Windows 10 setup this would happen after calling TForm's Print() 3 times. I tried both the Microsoft Print to PDF and the Microsoft XPS Document Writer and both gave the same error.

I did some quick debugging and found that it's the call to StartDoc() that returns a value <= 0.

A temp fix until I can figure out what is really causing this is to re-create the Printer object in Printers by calling

```
Vcl.Printers.SetPrinter(TPrinter.Create).Free;
```

after calling anything that is using the Printer object. Might not be advisable to do that, but it solved my issue for now.

Looks like something is not released properly when calling EndDoc()

Comment: Or, maybe just avoid using the singleton `TPrinter` object via the `Vcl.Printers.Printer()` function, and instead create a temporary `TPrinter` object whenever you want to print something, eg: `TPrinter *Prntr = new TPrinter; try { ... } __finally { delete Prntr; }` or simpler: `#include <memory> ... std::auto_ptr<TPrinter> Prntr(new TPrinter); ... `

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is really a [Microsoft problem](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3178466) and they should fix this buggy update. You can find more info at this on the [company site](https://support.seagullscientific.com/hc/en-us/articles/225047808-Windows-Update-causing-BarTender-errors).

Using a Printer Setup Dialog is only a workaround, not real solution, for this Microsoft bug. After confirmation, the printer setup dialog always creates a new handle for the printer. The next one or two print jobs will then succeed.

The patch should come from Microsoft, not from Embracadero. Thousands of programs are affected and it would be a massive waste of time and money to implement a workaround in all of them, if there is a bug in MS update.

Answer (score 0):

I started experiencing the same weird behavior at more or less the same time, when running 32 bit Delphi applications built in XE7 on a Windows 10 64 bit system.

After uninstalling the latest security upgrade for Windows 10 (KB3176493), printing from these applications works normally again.

A rather surprising side effect of uninstalling this update seems to be that the file associations - which are the default programs for handling specific file types - are being reverted to Microsoft Windows default values...

Answer (score 0):

The following variation of the code in the question will resolve the problem, but requires a `TPrinterSetupDialog` component added to the form:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::PrintButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Test Print:
    TPrinter *Prntr = Printer();
    Prntr->Title = "Test_";
    PrinterSetupDialog1->Execute();
    Prntr->BeginDoc();
    if (Prntr->Printing) {
        Prntr->Canvas->Font->Size = 10;
        Prntr->Canvas->TextOut(300,1050,"* * * Printing Test * * *");
        Prntr->EndDoc();
    }
}
```

For program usage, the user will be presented with the printer setup dialog before proceeding to printing.

As to "why", my best guess at this point is that `TPrinter` used alone does not have all necessary permissions to access all necessary resources from Windows after the Security *Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3177725)* was implemented on Aug 10, 2016. Somehow a call to `TPrinterSetupDialog` (or `TPrintDialog`) before calling `BeginDoc()` sets up the necessary conditions for `TPrinter` to perform successfully.

Comment: `TPrinterSetupDialog` calls the Win32 API [`PrintDlg()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646940.aspx), and then passes the resulting printer information to the `TPrinter.SetPrinter()` method.